# Assigning a pointer variable after freeing it

Tags: c++

```
if (currLength + 1 > maxLength)
{
    E *temp = new E[2 * maxLength]; // Doubling the chunk size
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = list[i];
    }
    maxLength *= 2; // the max size doubles
    delete[] list;
    list = temp;
    delete[] temp;
}
```

Can I assign another pointer to a pointer which is already freed? Is my code valid?
Will delete [] temp cause any problem for list?
Any suggestion would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: `delete` frees the memory pointed to by a pointer. It does not make that pointer variable unusable later on.

Comment: Thanks. 
will freeing temp cause any problem for the list?

Comment: Now list points to something which doesn't exist. Here be dragons.

Comment: Yes. As you are freeing `temp`, the address pointed by `list` will become invalid. Accessing that address will lead to problem

Comment: *"Is my code valid?"* -- that depends on context, specifically how `list` is defined, where the value (the pointer) of `list` came from, and how `list` is used after this code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you set `list = temp`, the two pointers are pointing to the same thing.  If you use `delete` on one of them, the other is now an invalid pointer and any attempt to use it would result in undefined behavior.  If you want to reuse `list` or `temp` you need to set it to something else.

Comment: Thanks, understood. It was really helpful.